# Auto Assign Public IP via Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I simply want the instance I'm creating to auto-assign its public IP just as it would if I was creating it through the web console, and ALSO have the instance assigned to the Security Group I created. Here is the relevant part of my template:

```
EC2Instance:
Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
Properties:
  ImageId: ami-xxxxxxx
  InstanceType: m5.xlarge
  KeyName: xxxxxxx
  Tags:
  - Key: Name
    Value: Instance_A
  NetworkInterfaces:
  - AssociatePublicIpAddress: true
    SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetA
    DeviceIndex: 0
    Description: Instance_A_Mgmt_Interface
    SecurityGroupIds: 
    - !Ref PublicSecurityGroup
```

When it's like this, I get the error "Encountered unsupported property SecurityGroupIds". When I move the SecurityGroupIds to the main Instance Properties section, I get the error, "Network interfaces and an instance-level security groups may not be specified on the same request". I don't understand why that would be and I can't find any answers from searching. When I stand up an instance using the Web Console I can tell it to auto-assign an IP AND put it in a Security Group. That's all I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `NetworkInterfaces`, Security Group IDs are provided using [GroupSet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-network-iface-embedded.html#aws-properties-ec2-network-iface-embedded-network-iface):

> The IDs of the security groups for the network interface.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thank you!